# Executar clique automático em input de form

Tags: javascript, funções, eventos, javascript-eventos

Tenho um form de pesquisa, e nele lista detalhes. ao acessar o detalhes ele grava sessão, mas ao retornar a lista grava a pesquisa na sessão mas não executa a pesquisa.

O que pensei é executar um input escondido com id="enviar", ao acessar ele faz um submit no formulário, assim retornar a página na mesma pesquisa do usuário.

Fiz assim

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $("#enviar").click();
                $(this).stop();
</script>
```

Mas ele esta em loop, parece que o stop não funciona, ou gostaria de executar uma unica vez essa função, mas não manjo tanto de javascript.

Alguém com uma dica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talvez o `.stop` não execute pois ele só irá ser processado no carregamento da página e não no descarregamento, não posso afirmar com convicção isso porque não tenho certeza do comportamento em diferentes motores de navegadores (webkit, blink, trident, gecko, etc), mas alguns caminhos que poderia optar são usar cookies ou os parametros na querystring (assim não afeta o POST).

Supondo que teu form seja algo como:

```
<form action="?send=1" method="POST">
...
<input type="submit" value="">
</form>
```

E no JavaScript checar:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Verifica se tem o GET com "expressão regular"
if (/\?send=1(&|$)|&send=1(&|$)/.test(window.location)) {
    $("#enviar").click();
}
</script>
```

Ou se sua página usa PHP pode checar se um dos campos POST foi enviado (ou melhor todos) usando `isset`:

```
<?php if (!isset($_POST['campo1'], $_POST['campo2'], $_POST['campo3'])): ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#enviar").click();
</script>

<?php endif; ?>
```

O `!isset($_POST['campo1'], $_POST['campo2'], $_POST['campo3'])` contém `!` e `isset`, é uma negação, ou seja se não existir campo1, campo2, campo3, significa que não veio do teu FORM e então irá executar o `.click`, acaso tenha vindo do FORM não irá entrar na IF e não irá executar novamente.

Ajuste os valores dentro de `isset` para os campos do teu FORM.

Comment: o meu form trabalha no PHP na mesma pagina sem refresh.
Então meu form esta assim:
`form class="form-inline" id="busca" method="POST" action="" `
Talvez eu não tenho entendido a sua segunda resposta, mas vamos ver a ideia.
Eu já faço uma verificação no campo
`if(!empty($select_empresa)){
  $sql_empresa = "AND empresa_id='$select_empresa' ";
 }`

Desta forma, eu acho que a sua segunda sugestão não condiz com o resultado que preciso.
Na verdade eu preciso que o click seja executado com o valor que já esta nos campos POST, e não limpa-lo, talvez entendi errado.

Comment: @MarceloRossi sim vc entendeu errado, eu dei um exemplo generico, pq eu não tenho como adivinhar a sua estrutura PHP atual, já que vc não a postou, não é mesmo? Então basta você adaptar o código que postei, as situações acima são exemplos simples, adaptando vão funcionar.

Comment: irei tentar aqui, adaptar como sugeriu. Muito obrigado pela colaboração.

Answer (score 0):

Faça dessa forma:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript">

        function sendForm() {
        $("#enviar").click();
      } 

        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="sendForm();">

    </body>
</html>
```

Dessa forma, a função 'sendForm' será criada e o método 'onload' irá chamar ela assim que a página for carregada.

Para mais informações sobre o onload, é só [clicar aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp).

Comment: Pode explicar porquê seu código é diferente do apresentado na pergunta?

Comment: Acabei de corrigir, realmente não tinha diferença. Dê uma olhada agora por favor.

Comment: Eu digo explicar no sentido de descrever através de texto a sua resposta. Nem todos os usuários terão conhecimento para abstrair o que você fez apenas lendo o código.

Comment: Não tem muito segredo, tentei explicar um pouco do que foi feito. Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss fora que o problema não é com enviar, o proprio AP disse que o problema é o LOOP infinito.

Comment: @Samuel - Sua solução funcionou como a minha, mas continua em loop o resultado. a pagina fica sendo carrega, preciso de uma solução a qual realize somente um evento de click, e não em loop. Mas obrigado pela sua colaboração.